# question from real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

suppose we are given a function $f$ such that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have the relationship that $ |\sup(f'(x))| < 1 $. We must to prove that for any $\{s_n\} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s_n=f(s_{n-1})$ the sequence is ${s_{n}}$ is convergent.

I first used the fact that $ |f'(x)| < 1 $ which would imply that $ -x<f(x)<x $. Substituting $ x=s_n$ in the relation I get that $s_{n}$ is a decreasing sequence but how to show that it is bounded below so that I can conclude that it is convergent !

Comment: Note that $|f'(x)| < 1$ doesn't imply $-x < f(x) < x.$  The closest we can get is $-|x| < f(x) - f(0) < |x|.$

Comment: @BrianMoehring thanks then what suggestions do you have ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c=\sup_x |f(x)|$. Then $|s_{n+1}-s_n|= |f(s_n)-f(s_{n-1})|\leq c|s_n -s_{n-1}|$ by Mean Value Theorem. By iteration this gives $|s_{n+1}-s_n|\leq c^{n-1} |s_2 -s_1|$. Now $|s_{n+m}- s_n| \leq |s_{n+m} -s_{n+m-1}|+|s_{n+m-1} -s_{n+m-2}|+...+|s_n -s_{n-1}|$. Hence $|s_{n+m}-s_n| \leq [c^{n-1}+c^{n}+...+c^{n+m-1}]|s_2-s_1|$. Use the convergence of the series $\sum c^{n}$ to conclude that $(s_n)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent.

Comment: sir that is a nice proof ! elegant one indeed ! but if you have time could you somehow develop a proof based on my starting point?

Comment: $|f'(x)|<1$ does not imply $-x <f(x) <x$. The proof I have given is standard and I don't think there is a simpler proof.